# Format Date type in WSH (and difference with date oject)

Tags: javascript, date, wsh

I'm trying to to some simple file comparaison in WSH, using the Javascript syntax.
I'm using windows XP SP3, and the script is run through Cscript.exe

My problem comes from the dateLastModified property of the File object, wich do not handle the usual date manipulation function - like getDay() or getFullYear()

It seems Microsoft Javascript has two type of date
Here's a sample of code :

```
var fso = WSH.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
f = fso.getFile('C:\\WINDOWS\\notepad.exe')
WSH.echo(f.Name)
WSH.echo(f.dateLastModified +" |type = "+ typeof(f.dateLastModified))


var d = new Date()
WSH.echo(d +" |type = "+ typeof(d))
```

And here's the output I get

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. Tous droits réservés.

notepad.exe
Sun Apr 13 19:34:16 UTC+0200 2008 |type = date
Tue Jul 17 14:28:08 UTC+0200 2012 |type = object
```

and of course, if I try :

```
WSH.echo( f.dateLastModified.getFullYear() )
```

I get an error, telling f.dateLastModified is not an object

So, I know how to manipulate the classic Date object, 
but how do I do the same about this date type the fileSystemObject is giving me ?

Is it possible to convert one type to another ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a `date` value to a `Date` object by creating a new `Date` object using the value as the object constructor's parameter. Like below example:

```
var fileDate = new Date( f.dateLastModified );
WSH.echo( fileDate + ' |type = ' + typeof(fileDate) );
WSH.echo( fileDate.getFullYear());
```

To convert a `Date` object to a `date` value, use this:

```
var dateVal = fileDate.getVarDate();
WSH.echo( dateVal + ' |type = ' + typeof(dateVal) );
```

Comment: Working great ! I just wonder why would I convert a Date object back to a date value ?

Comment: @dev.greg: The `date` value type is the one used by Visual Basic and ActiveX objects. The `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is an example of one of those ActiveX objects. Some object methods require `date` value as their parameters, and fortunately, JavaScript can convert `Date` value to `date` value automatically (but not the opposite). The `getVarDate` method is probably the same method that is used for auto-conversion and was made accessible for the sake of flexibility. Like `toString` and `valueOf` methods.